# Align siunitx numbers in a tabu table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, tabu

The minimal example below gives me a strange offset in numbers with exponential numbers. I think tabu and siunitx are getting in each others way. Is anyone aware of a workaround?

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabu,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype Z{X[c,m]{%
S[%
tight-spacing = true,
round-mode=places,
round-precision=2,
]
}}
\tabucolumn Z
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[l,m,1.2]ZZZZZ}
\hline
Water vapour* & 18.01534 & -2.418379e+8 & 1.886964e+5 &
2.605& 572.4\\
\hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The author of `tabu` is very active on comp.text.tex, but not here. You might want to (also) ask this question there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question was answered by the developer on comp.text.tex and I thought I share it here to answer the question:

> Well. In next version, thank to Bruno
>   Le Floch rewritting process, there is
>   no     \tabucolumn command:

```
\newcolumntype Z{ XS[m,
 tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,
                          round-precision=2] }
```

> X[options]{S[option]} is implemented
>   as XS[ X option , S option] but both
>   still work.
>
> \tabucolumn indeed has no signifiance:
>   I put it there due to some potential
>   parsing problems of the tabu preamble.
>   Problems that no more exist thank to B
>   Le Floch.
>
> XS ( or X[..]{S[...]} ) is always
>   centered: there is no point to set the
>   horizontal alignment for S and s
>   columns: the alignment can't be
>   chosen.
>
> `\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[l,m,1.2]ZZZZZ}`
>
> Avoid   X[l,m,1.2]   -> for XS columns
>   the comma is "reserved" to separate
>   the options of X with the options for
>   S. Thus it's good practice not to use
>   any delimiter for X options :
>            X [1.2 lm]   (and more readable imho)

```
\hline
 Water vapour*&  18.01534&  -2.418379e+8&  1.886964e+5&
 2.605&  572.4\\
 \hline
\end{tabu}
```

> Now the problem of the vertical
>   alignment: ;-)
>
> The problem is not tabu but siunitx
>   (sorry ;-( ): siunitx leaves too much
>   fixed space before the numbers,
>   because the S column mechanism
>   proceeds with "fixed width". To be
>   able to adjust the spacing, the S
>   column should read the whole tabular
>   and then choose the spacing depending
>   on the "natural length" of each
>   typeset number in each column.
>
> This is what is done inside tabu X,
>   but tabu cannot adjust the spacing
>   made by siunitx: the spaces are inside
>   a box, and tabu can't destroy the box
>   (and thereafter re-align the numbers !
>   )
>
> If you try with:

```
 \newcolumntype Z{X[-1
 m]{S[tight-spacing =
 true,round-mode=places,
round-precision=2]}}


 \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[lm] |
 *5{Z|}} \hline Water vapour* & 18.01534 & -2.418379e+8 & 1.886964e+5 &
 2.605& 572.4\\ \hline \end{tabu}
```

> There is no more problems of
>   alignment. But the columns width are
>   not the same. You can understand the
>   problem with :

```
 \newcolumntype Z{S[tight-spacing =
 true,round-mode=places,
 round-precision=2]}

\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[-1 lm] |
*5{Z|}} \hline Water \par vapour* & 18.01534 & -2.418379e+8 & 1.886964e+5 &
2.605& 572.4\\ \hline \end{tabu}
```

> This shows that siunitx needs more
>   space than the X coefs allow. Hence
>   the line break inside the X[m] ( ie m
>   ) column.
>
> So: change your margin, or
>   artificially raise the tabu width:

```
 \newcolumntype Z{X[m]{S[tight-spacing
 = true,round-mode=places,
 round-precision=2]}}
 \hskip-10mm \begin{tabu} to 500pt
 {X[-1 lm] | *5{Z|}} \hline Water \par
 vapour* & 18.01534 & -2.418379e+8 &
 1.886964e+5 &
 2.605& 572.4\\ \hline \end{tabu}
```

> Here there is no more problem. (for
>   future version 2.9 at least)

Comment: This answer confuses me.

Comment: @einpoklum If you could explain what confuses you, someone might be able to help